# How to subset a data.table in i (eg finding NAs) based on a character vector of column names

Tags: r, data.table

This should be easy but google and me are failing. Say I have this data:

```
library(data.table)

mydata <- data.table(a = c(1, NA),
                     b = c(NA, NA),
                     pointer = c(1,2))
```

and I want to get the rows where both `a` and `b` are `NA`. Of course i can do this manually like:

```
mydata[is.na(a) & is.na(b)]
```

but the issue arises deep in other code and I want to do this based on a character vector (or list, or whatever, this is flexible) of the column names such as:

```
myvector <- c("a","b")
```

again I can do this manually if I know how many elements the vector has:

```
mydata[is.na(get(myvector[1])) & is.na(get(myvector[2]))]
```

But I don't know how many elements `myvector` has in my application. How can I do this without specifying the number of entries in `myvector`? Essentially, I'm looking for something like `with = F` but for `i` in `data.table`. So I want to use `myvector` like this:

```
mydata[is.na(somefunction(myvector))]
```

I tried all kind of `paste0(myvector, collapse = " & ")` combinations with `get()` or `as.formula()` but it is getting me nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the `.SDcols` with the vector of column names, loop over the `.SD` (Subset of Data.table), create a `list` of logical vectors with `is.na` and `Reduce` the `list` to a single logical vector with `&` (which checks the corresponding elements of the `list` or column with `&` condition), use that to subset the rows of data

```
library(data.table)
mydata[mydata[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na)), .SDcols = myvector]]
```

-output

```
#   a  b pointer
#1: NA NA       2
```

---

Or use `mget`

```
mydata[mydata[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(mget(myvector), is.na))]]
```

Comment: how in the world did I never hear of the reduce function... Thanks!

Comment: eventually Reduce(&) can become pall(), for now this is the best approach, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution assuming that `myvector` is a character vector:

```
library(data.table)
mydata[rowSums(!is.na(mydata[, ..myvector])) == 0]
```